# Google Drive Error D41D "Unspecified Error" when trying to upload/sync large amount of files (1TB/700 Thousand files)

Tags: windows, google-drive

When I try to sync a large amount of files on Windows 10, Google drive will crash with `Google Drive Error D41D "Unspecified Error"`.

The crash might happen before any files are synced. It basically renders Google drive useless.

This issue has been bugging a lot of people for several months:

- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/NfwlYCdMDtQ
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/mo298Ko1vUY
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/_URUjl_mHTc
- https://monastyrskiy.ru/?p=3551

Answer (score 1):

if your PC is named using East Asian (Chinese/Japanese) or maybe other non-latin character sets, Google Drive will crash with this error.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

`D41D` is a memory issue. 
Since Google drive is still a 32-bit application, it cannot use more than 2GB memory unless it has been patched with "4GB Patch" (http://www.ntcore.com/4gb_patch.php).

In my cases, Google drive will consume 2.5GB memory to sync 1TB data. So "4GB patch" is definitely needed.

Before Google fixes this issue, it is better to turn off the auto-update of Google drive. Otherwise you will have to reapply "4GB Patch" whenever Google drive is updated.